# Simple way to adjust an individual subplot's width?

Tags: python, matplotlib

`aspect='equal'` plots almost a line for long vectors, whereas `='auto'` plots it as a matrix, which isn't desired either. How can I force `vec` to appear as SMALLVEC? I've seen related SO's, but they're all rather verbose and add much code in my application - is there something short, like `ax.set_width()`? Preferably `ax` is from a `plt.subplots()`'s `axes`.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Code**:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

KWS = dict(weight='bold', fontsize=14)

def plot_auto(mat, vec):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    plt.suptitle("AUTO", **KWS)
    axes[0].imshow(mat, aspect='auto')
    axes[1].imshow(vec, aspect='auto')
    plt.show()

def plot_equal(mat, vec):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    plt.suptitle("EQUAL", **KWS)
    axes[0].imshow(mat, aspect='auto')
    axes[1].imshow(vec, aspect='equal')
    plt.show()

def plot_smallvec(smallvec):
    plt.imshow(smallvec)
    plt.title("SMALLVEC", **KWS)

np.random.seed(0)
mat = np.random.randn(500, 500)
vec = np.random.randn(500, 1)
smallvec = np.random.randn(25, 1)

plot_auto(mat, vec)
plot_equal(mat, vec)
plot_smallvec(smallvec)
```

Comment: You mean `aspect=25` ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Didn't work; tried a wide range of values, seems to have no effect. [aspect](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html) `num` seems to describe itself mediating the _ratio_ between height and width, as desired, but I'm not observing that.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't do the math for your specific case... but try `aspect=1/20`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I guess I should've tried on the "logarithmic wide" range; perfect, it works - can submit it as an answer and I'll accept. P.S. the general value seems to be `aspect = 20 / len(vec)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) for suggesting the use of the third option for the [`aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html) parameter (`num`). I figured it might be useful to include the general formula if you want to match the aspect generated by a different shape array. The formula is

```
(reference.shape[0] / reference.shape[1]) / (target.shape[0] / target.shape[1])
```

Where `reference` is the array whose plotted aspect you wish to match and `target` is the array to be plotted with matching aspect. Including this in your example code,

```py
# ...
def plot_equal(mat, vec, smallvec):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    plt.suptitle("EQUAL", **KWS)
    axes[0].imshow(mat, aspect='auto')
    axes[1].imshow(vec, aspect=(smallvec.shape[0] / smallvec.shape[1]) / 
                   (vec.shape[0] / vec.shape[1]))
    plt.show()

# ...
plot_equal(mat, vec, smallvec)
```

Gives

[image]

---

**Note**   -   This formula may break down depending on other mutations to the figure, but within the scope of the example code it works correctly.